# Passing Data from Controller to Webform Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a asp.net mvc application. One of it's controller calls an **aspx** page instead of normal razor view page. I followed this https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx
Now the problem is I need to send some data from my controller to that aspx page which I can't do using **Viewbag**.

Any idea how can I send data from my regular controller to my aspx page?

Comment: what about your `model`? you should not use only `ViewBag` then you have still `ViewData` & `TempData`

Comment: I am not sure if I can use them on aspx as well.
For clarification I need something like this
 <Configuration  EnableAsyncUpload=@ViewBag.status/>

Comment: I think querystring is one of the options to pass data from MVC to Web forms application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing data using `model` to `view(aspx engine)` from `controller`:

**Model:**

```
public class Product  
{  
    public string ProductID { get; set; }  
    public string  ProductName { get; set; }  
    public int Quantity { get; set; }           
    public int Price {get; set;}
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()  
{  
    List<Product> productLst = new List<Product>{
        new Product{ProductID="P01",ProductName="Pen",Quantity=10,Price=12},
        new Product{ProductID="P02",ProductName="Copy",Quantity=12,Price=20},
        new Product{ProductID="P03",ProductName="Pencil",Quantity=15,Price=22},
        new Product{ProductID="P04",ProductName="Eraser",Quantity=20,Price=27}        
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your message comes here"; 
    return View();  
}
```

**ASPX View:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Product>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>Passing Data From Controller To View using ViewData</h3>
        <h3><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) %></h3>             
        <%foreach (var item in Model)
        {  %>
            <p><%=item.ProductID %></p>
            <p><%=item.ProductName %></p>
            <p><%=item.Quantity %></p>
            <p><%=item.Price %></p>
        <%} %>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

References for model binding in aspx engine,

- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/391289/Implementing-ASP-NET-MVC-Views-in-three-different
- https://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-mvc-3-using-multiple-view-engines-in-same-project

Assign dynamic HTML attribute for any HTML tags:

```
<input checked="@isRazor" type="checkbox"><!-- Razor engine -->
<input checked="<%:isASPX%>" type="checkbox"><!-- ASPX engine -->
```

You can do more mixing of HTML tags with Razor and ASPX View Engine, Following code block shows how you can do that.

`Your Sample Html Code or Text @RazorCode (@AnotherRazorCode)`

`Your Sample Html Code or Text <%: ASPXCode %> (<%:AnotherASPXCode %>)`

Comment: Thanks a ton, I could retrive my data through ViewData
But I want to set it as a property like this
   <Configuration  EnableAsyncUpload="false" ViewPaths=<%=Html.Encode(ViewData["uploadPath"]) %>/>
Can't I set it as ViewPath property?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that, You can go with creating your own **Custom Model** to passing the data from Controller to View.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<YourModel>" %>

<% foreach(var item in Model) { %>
<tr>
    <td><%: item.Name %></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing it through ViewData, like so?

in the action: `ViewData["myvar"] = "realvalue";`

in the view: `string parl = ViewData["myvar"];`

**NOTE:** Alternatively you can use `Session` like this example:

in MVC action:

```
Session["UserName"] = "Test";
```

in WebForms:

```
string UserName = (string)Session["UserName"];
```

That is all!